# jQuery populate list like ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am wondering what is the best way to create repeating elements for a list in jquery, such as posts in a blog etc.

I guess I'm asking if theres something more like ng-repeat with just jquery. Right now, I'm just manually creating every element with jquery, giving them an id + the position in the array. This doesn't seem like a very elegant solution to me, and makes reusing components even messier.

I read into html templates, but that seems to be manipulated using pure JS without a jquery solution.

What would be the best way to clone a template or an element with children in jquery?

Comment: What HTML are you trying to create from what data? As it stands this question is too broad to be answered concisely, and seems to require a discussion - which is explicitly off-topic, or against the rules, for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Just like a series of divs with a view spans and textareas in it. I'd like a way to edit the individual spans and textareas in each one I generate. Overall, I don't think it would matter too much exactly the elements I had in each div.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38422137/1271037